# Why I'm getting Erroe: Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression no-unused-expressions

Tags: reactjs

```
class Tweet extends React.Component{
    render(){
        return(
            <div className="tweet">
                <ShowTweet linkAvatar={this.props.link} name={this.props.name} userName={this.props.username} tweetText={this.props.content}/>
                <TweetAction />
                <Stats />
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

and

```
class TweetContainer extends React.Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
    }

    render(){

        const data =  [{name: 'Vuong xuan',username:'vuggg',content:'the good food'},
            {name: 'Jon tathoo',username:'tatoo',content:'the good food'}];

        let numberTweet = data.map(number=>{
            <Tweet linkAvatar={'/image/jennyshen.jpg'} name={number.name} userName={number.username} 
            tweetText={number.content} />
        });

        return(
            <div id="main">
                <h2>Tweet</h2>
                <div id="stream">
                    {numberTweet}
                </div>
            </div>
        );
```

I'm trying to show tweets, when running i get a error

./src/App.js
  Line 180:  Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  no-unused-expressions

Search for the keywords to learn more about each error.

line 180:

```
            tweetText={number.content} />
```

Comment: ah you are correct. i miss read that. deleted answer. but I am still looking at your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing a return keyword in data.map(). Look below:

```
class TweetContainer extends React.Component{
constructor(props){
    super(props);
}

render(){

    const data =  [{name: 'Vuong xuan',username:'vuggg',content:'the good food'},
        {name: 'Jon tathoo',username:'tatoo',content:'the good food'}];

    let numberTweet = data.map((number, index) => {
        return(
          <Tweet key={'Key-'+ index} linkAvatar={'/image/jennyshen.jpg'} name={number.name} userName={number.username} 
        tweetText={number.content} />
         )
        })

    return(
        <div id="main">
            <h2>Tweet</h2>
            <div id="stream">
                {numberTweet}
            </div>
        </div>
    );
```

Comment: i dont think so, i'm using arrow function, it does not need a return statement.

Comment: yes but the syntax is incorrect. you have open braces. you either need to add the return keyword or return like so => ({ <Tweet ... /> }). do you see the parenthesis?

Comment: More importantly key is required in Tweet component otherwise always only one Tweet will be rendered

Comment: you are correct @HemadriDasari. updated answer. not the best solution because people will argue that using index as a key is not good. but i think its ok for this usage.

Comment: Using index as key directly is not good but appending some string with index is good approach. like 'Key-'+index